# Why do does my jquery variable return undefined in firebug console

Tags: jquery, arrays, firebug, undefined

Here is my code:

```
var altArr = [];
i = 0;
$('ul.ctopics.topics img').each(function () {
    altArr[i++] = $(this).attr('alt')
});

var linkArr = [];
c = 0;
$('ul.ctopics.topics .activityinstance a').each(function () {
    linkArr[c++] = $(this).attr('href')
});

a = 0;
var scormId = [];
$('ul.ctopics.topics li.modtype_scorm').each(function () {
    scormId[a++] = $(this).attr('id')
});

b = 0;
var idArr = [];

$('.course-matrix .course-matrix-table tr').addClass('locked');

$('.course-matrix .course-matrix-table tr').each(function () {
    idArr[b++] = $(this).attr('id');
    idTr = $(this).attr('id');
    var matchArr = $.inArray(idTr, scormId);
    var selLink = linkArr[matchArr];
    var selAlt = altArr[matchArr];

    $(this).find('td.course-title').wrapInner('<a href="' + selLink + '" class="scorm-link"></a>');
    $(this).find('a.scorm-link').attr('title', selAlt);

    var alt = $(this).find('a.scorm-link').attr('title');
    var indexResult = alt.search("Not");

    if (indexResult >= 0) {
        $(this).removeClass('locked');
        $(this).addClass('not-yet-complete');
        $(this).addClass('unlocked');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('completed');
        $(this).addClass('unlocked');
        $(this).removeClass('locked');
    }
});
```

I can't find why I'm getting this error from Firebug. This breaks my succeeding JS codes:

```
TypeError: alt is undefined
var indexResult = alt.search("Not");
```

> spoiler to get rid of "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Can you add your HTML? Or make a JSFiddle?

Comment: why are your selectors written like that? are they supposed to be several selectors or one?

Comment: Here is the JS fiddel, I have simpified the Html and code... Hope somebady can help check why var selAlt is seen as undefined http://jsfiddle.net/A5rdV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding DOM elements dynamically and then searching for them. But as you add them, you can assign to a variable. Such as this (untested) but you get the idea:

Replace this:

```
$(this).find('td.course-title').wrapInner('<a href="'+selLink+'" class="scorm-link" title=""></a>');
$(this).find('a.scorm-link').attr('title', selAlt);

var alt = $(this).find('a.scorm-link').attr('title');
```

With something like this:

```
//first create your nodes, and remember them as variables. Use the $ prefix so you know it is a jquery object that is stored in the variable
var $td = $(this).find('td.course-title');
var $a = $('<a href="'+selLink+'" class="scorm-link"></a>');

//add the link to the cell
$td.append($a);

//then set your attribute. Note you already have the variable so no need to search
$a.attr('title', selAlt)

//if you need you can then extract that title attribute
var alt = $a.attr('title');
```

Comment: Thanks Action Dan, I tired it but, when I used alt, jquery still breaks, Alt var is still seen as undefined   var alt = $a.attr('title');
  var indexResult = alt.indexOf("Not");

Comment: @ARGO How about including the title to start with. 
var $a = $('<a href="'+selLink+'" class="scorm-link" title=""></a>');